# Bloquear inserção em box

Tags: javascript, html

No código eu crio duas box, uma patrimonio e outra serial:

```
<table border="0" align="center" height="100">
    <tr>
        <td>   
            <font face="arial" align="center" valign="middle" color="blue" size="-1">PATRIMÔNIO</font><br>
            <input type="text" name="tx_patr" id="id_patr" maxlength="12" size="12" style="font-size:11; color:Black;" onkeypress="return SomenteNumero(event);" onkeyup="Mascara(this,Patri);" value="">
            <input type="button" onClick="move_patr_seri(this.form.tx_patr,this.form.cb_Patr);limpa_patr();" value=">>">
            <br>
            <select multiple size="7" name="cb_Patr" style="width:300"></select>
            <br>
            <input type="button" align="center" valign="middle" onClick="tira(this.form.cb_Patr)" value="<<">
            <br>
        </td>
        <td align="center" valign="middle" width="15%">
        </td>
        <td>  
            <font face="arial" align="center" valign="middle" color="blue" size="-1">SERIAL</font><br>
            <input type="text" name="tx_seri" id="id_seri"  maxlength="15" size="15" style="font-size:11; color:Black;" onblur="evento(this)"  value="">
            <input type="button"  onClick="move_patr_seri(this.form.tx_seri,this.form.cb_Seri);limpa_seri();" value=">>">
            <br>
            <select multiple size="7" name="cb_Seri" style="width:300"></select>
            <br>
            <input type="button" align="center" valign="middle" onClick="tira(this.form.cb_Seri)" value="<<">
            <br>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Eu quero bloquear uma inserção numa box caso uma quantidade informada (vinda de um programa anterior) for atingida. Por exemplo:
  "Quantidade informada = 3, assim o usuário só pode inserir 3 patrimônios e se quiser 3 seriais. Caso queira inserir 4 patrimônios ou seriais ele deve ser bloqueado."!

EXEMPLO NO JSF: [Exemplo da box e o JavaScript de inserção](http://jsfiddle.net/Feelipee/90x7hzry/1/)

Obs* 
As variaveis que estão no JSF

```
var w_Qtde_Peri = 3; -> Quantidade informada
var w_Cont_Qtde = 0;
     var  w_ver = 1;
     var v_patr = new Array (w_Qtde_Peri);
```

são do `PHP`, por isso ele não irá incluir nas box!

Answer (score 1):

Consegui chegar a uma resposta para o meu problema!

No caso para bloquear, só preciso adicionar esse trecho:

```
 if((Destino.name == "cb_Seri") && (Destino.options.length == w_cont))
    { return false;} 
 if((Destino.name == "cb_Patr") && (Destino.options.length == w_cont))
    { return false;}
```

Onde `w_cont` recebe a quantidade informada, assim não permitindo que o usuário insira mais que a quantidade total na box!